# Can I define `eventBus` at a provider level?

Tags: serverless-framework

I have a custom event bus, and for each subscribing Lambda I have to define which bus to use.

For example:

```
functions:
    hello:
        handler: src/handlers/hello.main
        events:
            - eventBridge:
                  eventBus: 'arn:aws:events:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:event-bus/events-${opt:stage}'
                  pattern:
                      source:
                          - dynamodb-stream
    world:
        handler: src/handlers/world.main
        events:
            - eventBridge:
                  eventBus: 'arn:aws:events:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:event-bus/events-${opt:stage}'
                  pattern:
                      source:
                          - dynamodb-stream
```

Is it possible to define it at a provider level?

Such as:

```
provider:
    eventBridge:
        eventBus: 'arn:aws:events:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:event-bus/events-${opt:stage}'
```

Generally this pattern exists but it's not in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have repeated properties in your `yml` file, would be good to use an `anchors`:

```
functions:
    hello:
        handler: src/handlers/hello.main
        events: &funcEvents
            - eventBridge:
                  eventBus: 'arn:aws:events:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:event-bus/events-${opt:stage}'
                  pattern:
                      source:
                          - dynamodb-stream
    world:
        handler: src/handlers/world.main
        events: *funcEvents
```

But, unfortunately, you can not define it on the provider level.

In order to keep your function declarations clean to define your ARN in custom section like:

```
functions:
    hello:
        handler: src/handlers/hello.main
        events: &funcEvents
            - eventBridge:
                  eventBus: ${self:custom.eventBusArn}
                  pattern:
                      source:
                          - dynamodb-stream
    world:
        handler: src/handlers/world.main
        events: *funcEvents

custom:
  eventBusArn: arn:aws:events:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:event-bus/events-${opt:stage}
```

Comment: Also you can only define an existing bus with a string that starts with `arn`. Can't use refs.

Comment: @noetix not exactly. You are right, `Ref` could return only name, but `Fn::GetAtt` could return `Arn`, `Name` and even `Policy`

Comment: @noetix why did you edited my answer? what's wrong?

Comment: @dobeeman sls framework needs a string starting with `arn`, CloudFormation refs aren't evaluated at this point.

Comment: What is `&funcEvents`?

Comment: @noetix this is the anchor for reuse the property. Please don't edit foreign comments ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217155/discussion-between-dobeerman-and-noetix).